# Whats happening in Mootools with for (var x in data) loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, mootools

This situation came about when I was trying to squeeze a google analytics plugin that uses jQuery into my site which uses mootools throughout.

The jQuery code uses a loop similar to the one in the code with no issues.

http://jsfiddle.net/RzBh5/2/

```
var myData = [[20130105,0,0],[20130106,0,0],[20130107,0,0],[20130108,3,44],[20130109,2,6],[20130110,0,0]]
for (var r in myData) {
$('results').set('html',$('results').get('html') + '<br>' + myData[r][0] + ' - ' + r);
}
```

The same loop in Mootools adds all the new methods it adds to the array class to the array I've built. Can someone explain whats happening and how I can rewrite this loop in normal javascript or jQuery so that it doesnt happen.

The 'mootools' way to do this loop which works fine is;

```
Array.each(myData, function(stuff, index){
$('resultsMoo').set('html',$('resultsMoo').get('html') + '<br>' + stuff[0]);
});
```

The fiddle justs spits out the contents of the array object.

Thanks

Comment: Don't ever use `for(x in array)`. This is the very reason why you shouldn't.

Comment: there are plenty of unis that teach that - just about every candidate I have interviewed in the last 3 months does that.

Answer (score 4):

A plain `for ... in` loop lists all methods and properties of an object including those inherited via the prototypes.

To limit the loop to those properties and methods, that are unique to the respective object, you can use [`hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).

In this case, however, it is just an array to loop through, which you should use a plain `for` loop like this:

```
for( var i=0; i<myData.length; i++ ) {
   $('results').set('html',$('results').get('html') + '<br>' + myData[i][0] + ' - ' + i );
}
```

**EDIT**

An array is at its core an object like any other. In JavaScript there is a native object called `Array`, which all arrays inherit their functions from.

So when you use a `for ... in` loop all the methods of the parent object `Array` are listed as well as the new properties of the array itself like the values.

Hope this explanation helps a little.

Comment: I didnt write the plugin code but once its changed to a normal for loop it works fine. Can you explain why this happens, its not clear from the construction why it would start listing all methods and properties of an object and I'm not enough of an OOP expert to see it. Thanks

Comment: Its ok I am just being lazy I will go search out more details about why this happens now I know its just a consequence of using for (x in array).

Comment: @RolfHerbert Added some more explanations.